# Is it possible to "over edit"?

Tags: discussion, best-practice, editing

Hi!

Since it's beta I want to make sure we have high quality questions and answers. As a result I've been doing some editing, but a bunch of it things like capitalization, spelling, formatting, etc. which I think are minor things.

However this bumps the question. Do you think it interferes with the "flow" of what people are discussing if I flood the page with edits? Right now I am trying to kind of space it out so I don't clobber the page too much. Any advice?

Comment: Thank you for asking this. It's very helpful, even to me a year later. I've been doing tons of editing and I'm glad to know it isn't going to become a burden to those who approve my edits.

Comment: @JorgeCastro.I have a suspicion. Since editing bumps the question in the home page. I often edit (minor) my unanswered questions to give a chance. Is it correct.?

Comment: That's what you're supposed to do. Though don't waste it with a minor edit, add some useful information to get a better chance of getting it answered!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No. I'm a believer in the religion of editing, overediting and superediting.

Quality content usually comes from work, overwork and superwork ;).

Answer (score 2):

> Do you think it interferes with the "flow" of what people are discussing if I flood the page with edits?

Yes and no.  This isn't a discussion site; yet people discussing in comments and watching for new answers won't be affected.  But it does interfere with people looking at the homepage to see recently active questions.  However, AU has enough activity now to restore that fairly quickly.  OTGH, if several people do this often, that would be a problem.

I believe you should still do this kind of editing.  It helps to lump all the edits for a single page together; so instead of coming back later for subsequent edits and edits to other posts (i.e. answers or the question if you originally were editing an answer), get it all done at once.

Comment: I am also finding that editing older answers in chunks for a specific tag (or whatever) also gives those older questions another chance at being answered.