# Is editing too much, an annoyance?

Tags: support, editing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to “over edit”?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/309/is-it-possible-to-over-edit)

I'm kind of a perfectionist of sorts when it comes to my writing. I often go back, and edit my posts days later if I notice something that could be easier to read, better formatted, or even need a simple change of wording. I've seen a few instances where an edited question is "bumped" to the top of the page, and I certainly would not want to crowd the main page with all of my edits.

So my question is, is it frown upon, editing too many of my own posts in a certain amount of time, thus crowding the page?